# After clicking on an actionlink, how do I reference back to its linkText?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

Say I have a table that begins like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Things", new { someId = item.Id})
        </td>
```

And it takes me to the view for that specific item. Once I am in that separate .cshtml file, how can I reference back to the original "item.Name" string that appeared in this ActionLink?

*** SOLUTION EDIT ***

The solution ended up looking like this.

The ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Things", new { someId = item.Id, someName = item.Name})
```

The Action:

```
public ActionResult Things(Guid? someId, string someName)
...
ViewBag.currentName = someName;
```

The other View:

```
<h2>@ViewBag.currentName</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have to reference to first `ActionLink` argument. What might interest you is an object which is a `Model` for this view. When you click the link you will navigate to action where you pass the `someId` - `id` of current model object. Then probably you should find an object by its `id` in your storage. It will have `.Name` property that was used as `ActionLink` argument.

However if you just need exactly the same string you've used as a first argument in `ActionLink` which can be any string you should duplicate it in route values. Your `Things` action should accept not only `someId` argument but also this string. After you should pass this string via `Model` or `ViewBag`/`ViewDictionary` to your view.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up going for the ViewBag approach. The part that was getting me earlier was not including it in the Things action.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an extra parameter with the name of the item

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Things", new { someId = item.Id, name = item.Name})
```

You will need to modify your controller and model too for this approach.

Comment: I guess, not your Model, but only the Controller to recieve the new parameter. Once you have, you can pass it via ViewData to the next View

Comment: Thats personal :-), I like things to be in my ViewModel, if it can be added

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could mark both answers as correct as I did end up doing this, but the other answer helped with additional concerns.